# JPA Problem, Using Parent Entity's Primary Key for Child's Entity's Primary Key

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm currently developing my project under Spring with JPA.

First off, here is my database schema for the background information

[image: Database Schema]

So, I'm undergoing difficulties when I try to use history_id of HISTORY as the primary key of TAG. It gives me `...Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class com.wrapsody.demo.HistoryTag] does not define an IdClass` error.

So I added `@IdClass(HistoryTag.HistoryTagAssignId.class)` in my HistoryTag.java

```
 @NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)  @Data @Entity
 @IdClass(HistoryTag.HistoryTagAssignId.class)  
 public class HistoryTag implements Serializable {
     @Id
     @ManyToOne
     private History history;

     @Column
     private String tagName;

     @Builder
     public HistoryTag(String tagName) {
         this.tagName = tagName;
     }

     @NoArgsConstructor
     public static class HistoryTagAssignId implements Serializable {
         private History history;

         public HistoryTagAssignId(History history) {
             this.history = history;
         }
     } 
}
```

For the reference, this is History.java

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Data
@Entity
public class History {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long historyId;

    @Column
    private String historyMaterName;

    @Column
    private String historyFreeSetName;

    History(String historyMaterName, String historyFreeSetName) {
        this.historyMaterName = historyMaterName;
        this.historyFreeSetName = historyFreeSetName;
    }
}
```

Any guidance towards solving this error msg is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi i don't see any child parent relationship between these two classes i tried to run the same code in my local its working fine for me.

Comment: I used @ManyToOns annotation in HistoryTag.java

Comment: ok that's  association between entities

Comment: you mean there is no problem??.. why did it show me errors..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tag table you dont need entity class. Its duable in History entity with:

```
  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(
        name="TAG",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="HISTORY_ID")
  )
  @Column(name="TAG_NAME")   
  List<String> tags;
```

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection#Basic_Collections